Next JS app not rendering properly after delete function
When testing on my local environment this works fine but when pushed to the main branch and deployed on Vercel with a Postgres DB it behaves strangely. Creating projects and skills works fine but when deleting anything these are deleted from the DB but the site is not updated properly and more projects disappear although they are still in the DB.
skill-view-card.tsx
'use client'

import { deleteSkill, createProject, deleteProject } from '@/app/lib/actions';
import { Button } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { TrashIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';


export default function SkillViewCard({ skills, projects }: { skills: string; projects: string }) { // after doing something these are fetching old ones
  const skillsParsed = JSON.parse(skills); // these need to refetch
  const projectsParsed = JSON.parse(projects);

  function toTitleCase(str: string) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, (text: string) => text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substring(1).toLowerCase());
  }

  return (
    <div className="p-8 border w-full h-full shadow-lg rounded-md bg-white">
      <div className="columns-2">
        <div className="text-left text-xl font-bold">
          {toTitleCase(skillsParsed?.description) || 'No description available'}
        </div>
        <Button onClick={() => { deleteSkill(skillsParsed.id);}}>
          <TrashIcon className="h-4 w-4 content-right" />
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className="columns-1">
        <fieldset>
          {projectsParsed && projectsParsed.length > 0 ? (
            projectsParsed
              .filter((project: { skill_id: string }) => project.skill_id === skillsParsed?.id)
              .map((project: { title: string, id: number }) => (
                <div key={project.id}>
                  <div>{project.title}</div>
                  <Button onClick={() => { deleteProject(project.id);}}>
                    <p>delete</p>
                  </Button>
                </div>
              ))
          ) : (
            <p className="text-gray-500">No projects available</p>
          )}
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div className="columns-2"></div>
      <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter project title"
                className="border rounded-md p-2 w-half"
                onKeyDown={(e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        const formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append('title', e.currentTarget.value);
                        formData.append('skill_id', skillsParsed.id);
                        createProject(formData);
                        e.currentTarget.value = '';
                    }
                }}
            />    
        </div>
  );
}

@/app/lib/actions
'use server';
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export async function createSkill(formData: FormData) {
    const skillDescription = formData.get('skill') as string | null;

    await sql`
    INSERT INTO skills (description)
    VALUES (${skillDescription || ''})
  `;

  redirect('/test-page?refetch=true'); // this needs to refetch the skills
}

export async function deleteSkill(id: number) {
    await sql`
    DELETE FROM skills WHERE id = ${id}
    `;

    redirect('/test-page?refetch=true');
}

export async function createProject(formData: FormData) {
    const projectTitle = formData.get('title') as string | null;
    const skillId = formData.get('skill_id') ? parseInt(formData.get('skill_id') as string, 10) : null;

    await sql`
    INSERT INTO projects (title, skill_id)
    VALUES (${projectTitle || ''}, ${skillId || ''})
  `;

  redirect('/test-page?refetch=true');
}

export async function deleteProject(id: number) {
    await sql`
    DELETE FROM projects WHERE id = ${id}
  `;
  redirect('/test-page?refetch=true');
}


There might be cache issue, so I recommend you would use revalidatePath.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath
What the important is server side, so you might need to use it with "use server"

This fixed it, thank you!

Cal, I'm happy that's fixed. Could you mark my answer to resolved kindly, so that can give helps for other users.
